# Converting from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php

Can anyone help me converting this code from PHP to C#?

```
$body = "{
  \"flow\": \"MATCH_CODE\",
  \"amount_unit\": 100,
  \"currency\": \"EUR\"
}";

$digest = base64_encode(hash("sha256", $body, true));
```

The first part seems to me a string declaration, the real PROBLEM is the last row.

---

### EDIT 13/08/2021 hour 17:05

After a lot of tries, I wrote this in C#:

```
string requestBody = "{\"flow\": \"MATCH_CODE\",\"amount_unit\": 100,\"currency\": \"EUR\"}";
byte[] tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody);

SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256Managed.Create();
byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(tmp);     
TextBox01.Text = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

In TextBox1.Text I see "6m6lp2lwPRpHJ3BkrGF4RCAvTTgLFTqCre/kC7M5EAg="

I made a virtual machine with Xampp, and I made a sample PHP page like this:

Test Digest";

$body = "{
  \"flow\": \"MATCH_CODE\",
  \"amount_unit\": 100,
  \"currency\": \"EUR\"
}";
echo  "

body = " . $body . "

";

$aaa = hash("sha256", $body, true);
echo "

aaa = " . $aaa . "

";

$bbb = base64_encode($aaa); 
echo "

bbb = " . $bbb . "

";

$digest = base64_encode(hash("sha256", $body, true));
echo "

digest = " . $digest . "

";
?>

Digest is "E8oVvSVzNhmF4sskhK7XW0EnOG/likDYwI/NDVpDBKA="
Totally different from the C# result.

Comment: Post what you have thus far. Describe what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

These should point you in the right direction:

using [SHA256.HashData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.hashdata?view=net-5.0)

to hash a byte[] to output byte[]

[System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0)

to make your body from a string to a byte[]

[Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0)

to make the hash output byte[] to a base64 string